# Error 403 when display imagens from another page

Tags: python, flask, http-status-code-403

I need to collect images of a given page and display them in another. I am using Selenium + [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/) + Flask to do this.

I got a list of the addresses of images that will show using Selenium + PhantomJS. However, when I try view them in my local page using Flask, I always get 403 error in return.

```
GET https://example.net/thumbnails/large/1015/1015729.jpg 403 (Forbidden)
```

[image]

Is there any way to display these images on my page? I thought to make download with PhantomJS, however, it will consume a lot of memory; I would like to display them using the direct link from the original source.

The site where the images are any hosted is not mine.

Comment: The external website is preventing hot-linking by examining the `Host` header. Since your requests do not generate from their website, then you are prevented from consuming their bandwidth.

Comment: @StefanoSanfilippo You know how to work around this?

Comment: Yes, but if they don't allow hot linking, you should probably just respect their will and change your source if possible.